# Find rows with different values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a statement that brings up details of items in certain range. All details suppose to be the same like this..

```
 id | color |  shape | material |
----------------------------
 i45 | blue  | square | plastic  |
 i46 | blue  | square | plastic  |
 i47 | blue  | square | plastic  |
```

but in case the range wasn't defined properly like that :

```
id | color |  shape | material |
 ----------------------------
i45 | blue  | square | plastic  |
i46 | blue  | square | plastic  |
i47 | blue  | square | plastic  |
i48 | red   | square | plastic  |
```

I need  query to bring back column name that has a value that differs from others. The column name will be displayed in a pop up window.. At the moment I have a statement :

```
$chk = "SELECT DISTINCT
    color,
    shape,
    material,
FROM $table 
WHERE  id BETWEEN $StartID AND $EndID";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $chk) or die (mysqli_error($con));
$r = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if ($r > 1)

<script language="JavaScript">alert ("Some fields have different data")</script>
```

that only finds if there is different value .. But I'm stack on how to get the column name that has different value..
Please help..

Comment: Do you know about [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT count( DISTINCT color  ) as Color, count( DISTINCT shape  ) as shape, count( DISTINCT material) as Material
FROM $table;
```

Now those columns which has value greater than 1 have values which are distinct from others.

Comment: Look at your syntax. It may be wrong. I run the query in sqlfiddle.com it run very well. just refer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7f82/1